# Assign X and Y coordinates from separate lists into tuple

Tags: python

I'm developing a software that build a chart using X and Y datas.

I've created 2 lists that contain X and Y coordinates.
I'm trying to assign `X[0]` and `Y[0]` so as to form couples of coordinates like that: `tuple(X[0],Y[0])` but I've found this error:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

This is my code:

```
import random

first_data = ['S1',0,100]
X = ['','','','','','','','','']
Y = ['','','','','','','','','']
coordinates = ()

class SeriesGenerator:
        
    def generate_random(self):
        minV = first_signal[1]
        maxV = first_signal[2]
        for i in range(9):
            X[i] = minV+(maxV-minV)*random.random()
            Y[i] = minV+(maxV-minV)*random.random()
        return X,Y
    
    def create_axes(self):
        for e in Y:
            for u in X:
                coordinates(u,e)
                
        print(coordinates)
        
        
SeriesGenerator().create_axes()
```

Comment: The error is in the line ```coordinates(u, e)``` and should probably be something along the lines of  ```coordinates = (u, e)```

Comment: You have not said where the error is but I suspect it is in the “coordinates(u,e)” line. Python thinks this is a function call. What do you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call a tuple using `some_name(something)`. It means initializing a tuple object, which you already created. Try:

```py
coordinates = (u,e)
```

Comment: Can you explain more on the output print statement? What do you need the output looks like?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's correct. I forget to call the method

Answer (score 3):

In your code `coordinates` is a tuple with the value `()`, and you're trying to call it. Python doesn't have a call operator for tuples, hence the error. What you probably want is something like

```py
import random

first_data = ['S1',0,100]
X = ['','','','','','','','','']
Y = ['','','','','','','','','']
coordinates = []

class SeriesGenerator:
        
    def generate_random(self):
        minV = first_signal[1]
        maxV = first_signal[2]
        for i in range(9):
            X[i] = minV+(maxV-minV)*random.random()
            Y[i] = minV+(maxV-minV)*random.random()
        return X,Y
    
    def create_axes(self):
        for e in Y:
            for u in X:
                coordinates.append((u,e))
                
        print(coordinates)
        
        
SeriesGenerator().create_axes()
```